# Use terraform for google cloud run

Tags: terraform, google-cloud-run

Im looking into using terraform to automate setting up an environment for demos.

Works for VM instance and can be fully automated but management prefers to use Cloud run with Docker containers.

When I read [this article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/deploying-docker-images-to-cloud-run-using-terraform-ee8ae4ecb72e) it starts with manually having to build and register a docker container. I don't get that step, why can't that be automated as well with terraform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Terraform is a deployment tool. More or less, it invokes API to build, update or delete things. So now what do you want to do? To take a container and to deploy it on Cloud Run. Build sources, uploading files, perform git clone aren't actions designed for Terraform.

It's not surprising to have a CI pipeline that build things and at the end a CD tool called for the deployment.